# How do I implement event driven POSIX threads?

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, sockets, posix

I'm coding for a linux platform using C. Let's say I have 2 threads. A and B.

A is an infinite loop and constantly trying to find out if there is data on the socket localhost:8080, where as B is a thread that spends most of its time in a blocked state until A calls mutex unlock function on a mutex that B uses to block itself. A will unlock B when it received appropriate data on the socket.

So you see here is a problem. B is "event driven" largely whereas A is in a constant running state. My target platform isn't resource rich so I wish A could be "activated" and enter running state only when it received data on socket, instead of constantly looping.

So how can I do that? If it matters - I wish to do this for both UDP and TCP sockets.

Comment: If A is using blocking sockets, `recv()`/`recvfrom()` will naturally block until there is data ready to receive on the socket.  If A is using non-blocking sockets, you can call `select()` or `poll()` to block until data is ready to read on a socket.

Comment: You need to learn proper socket programming. One guide: https://beej.us/guide/bgnet/

Comment: https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/epoll.7.html

Answer (score 0):

There are Multiple was of doing what you want in a clean was. One approach, you are kind of using already, is a event system. A real event system would be overkill for the kind of problem you are dealing with, but can be found [here](https://github.com/rs22/rasta-protocol/blob/main/src/rasta/c/event_system.c). This is a (random) better implementation, capable of listening for multiple file descriptors and time based events, all in a single thread.

If you want to build one yourself, you should take a look at the `select` or `poll` function.

But I agree with @Jeremy Friesner, you should definitely use the functions made for socket programming, they are perfect for your kind of problem. Only use the event system approach if you really need it (with multiple sockets/timed events).

Comment: Are `select` and `poll` not considered to be superseded by `epoll`? With epoll, you can even do quite powerful event driven programming (custom events etc.) without a library. It is not hard to use. FreeBSD kqueue is about the same with a different API. So, the major benefit of a library is abstraction over different operating systems. On Windows it is IO completion ports.

Comment: Would work too, but I recommended select, because it does exactly what he wanted. Also the epoll man page is a bit overwhelming.

Answer (score 0):

You simply call `recv` (or `recvfrom`, `recvmsg`, etc) and it doesn't return until some data has been received. There's no need to "constantly try to find out if there is data" - that's silly.

If you set the socket to non-blocking mode then `recv` will return even if there's no data. If that's what you're doing, then the solution is simple: don't set the socket to non-blocking mode.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. How exactly do I find out whether my socket was initialized as blocking? I think I did but I'm not sure.